# execute a function after 2 other functions returns a desired response vanilla js

Tags: javascript, execute, pure-js

I have a project which contains a form of two cells one is a text and another is a date.
I have 2 JS files that validate each cell
I want if the text field and date field have a correct inputs to execute the new function. and if not show alert messages I coded in other JS files
I tried a lot but I can't figure what is the problem?

**the first JS file**

```
export function daysRemaining() {
  document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //console.log("I'm there from search form");
    const today = new Date(); //today date
    const tripDate = new Date(document.getElementById('date').value); //trip date entered by user
    if (tripDate > today) {
      console.log(
        Math.ceil(Math.abs(tripDate - today) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
      );
    }
  });
}
```

**the second file**

```
export function checkDestinationAndDate() {
  document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const destination = document.querySelector('#destination').value;
    const tripDate = new Date(document.getElementById('date').value);
    if (!destination && !Date.parse(tripDate)) {
      alert('Enter a destination and a date');
    } else if (destination && !Date.parse(tripDate)) {
      alert("You didn't choose a date");
    } else if (!destination && Date.parse(tripDate)) {
      alert("You didn't choose a destination");
    } else if (destination && Date.parse(tripDate) < new Date()) {
      alert('Please pick a future date');
    } else {
      console.log(destination);
    }
  });
}
```

***the third JS file and what I want to edit ***

```
import { daysRemaining } from './days_countdown';
import { checkDestinationAndDate } from './destination_date';

export function main() {

  document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (daysRemaining === true && checkDestinationAndDate === true) {
      console.log('good work');
    } else {
      console.log('Failed');
    }
  });
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return boolean value from the exported functions. You don't need click handler for each function. The final function `main()` can listen for click event.

EDIT: you need to `export` functions if separated into modules. Please check the codesandbox link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-execute-a-function-after-2-other-functions-returns-a-desired-response-vanilla-js-rcze7?file=/src/index.js

Here is the snippet that might help you.

```js
function daysRemaining() {
  //console.log("I'm there from search form");
  const today = new Date(); //today date
  const tripDate = new Date(document.getElementById('date').value); //trip date entered by user
  if (tripDate > today) {
    const isRemaining = Math.ceil(Math.abs(tripDate - today) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
    console.log(isRemaining);

    return !!isRemaining
  }

  return false;
}

function checkDestinationAndDate() {
  const destination = document.querySelector('#destination').value;
  const tripDate = new Date(document.getElementById('date').value);
  let returnValue = false;

  if (!destination && !Date.parse(tripDate)) {
    alert('Enter a destination and a date');
  } else if (destination && !Date.parse(tripDate)) {
    alert("You didn't choose a date");
  } else if (!destination && Date.parse(tripDate)) {
    alert("You didn't choose a destination");
  } else if (destination && Date.parse(tripDate) < new Date()) {
    alert('Please pick a future date');
  } else {
    returnValue = true;
    console.log(destination);
  }

  return returnValue;
}

// import { daysRemaining } from './days_countdown';
// import { checkDestinationAndDate } from './destination_date';

function main() {

  document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (checkDestinationAndDate() && daysRemaining()) {
      console.log('good work');
    } else {
      console.log('Failed');
    }
  });
}

main()
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date" />
<input type="text" id="destination" />

<button type="button" id="search">Search</button>
```

Comment: It works if all fields are not empty. but, It didn't work for me. when I press the search button it logs it consoled "failed" if the text input and date are empty. but it supposes to alert me if they are empty or one of them is empty with one of these alert messages
I split the code into 3 files as I mention in my original post as it is a webpack project. I imported the first two files to the main.js file

Comment: --edit -- 
your code is working if all code in one file, but if I split it into  3 files. It won't work

Comment: please note that I have removed the `export` keyword. Add them back when you split those functions  to different files

Comment: I put export and I add event listener to each function to interact with the user. then export all three function to index.js <<webpack entry >>. It works fine but always returns failed. I can't figure what is the problem and cannot post my edited code in comment. So I put the code in **code pen** here is the [link] (https://codepen.io/mohammedkhairy/project/editor/XvkYVj#0)

Comment: please check this link for working code. https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-execute-a-function-after-2-other-functions-returns-a-desired-response-vanilla-js-rcze7?file=/src/index.js Also you need to do `if (checkDestinationAndDate() && daysRemaining() )` since this will do short circuit evaluation and daysRemaining will return false if date is not filled